# Prevent app from backing up files in the documents folder?

Tags: swift, file, icloud

I am not able the test my case, because I simply don't know when the synchronisation process of syncing files is triggered. Thats why I am asking this here.
I have a lot of files and subfolders in my apps document folder and want to prevent from backup up these files in ICloud (which seems to be stupidly the default).
Is it necessary to mark all these files with

```
MyFile.setResourceValue(NSNumber.numberWithBool(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &err)
```

or is it good enough to only mark the root document folder once and all childs will also be marked with ExcludedFromBackup implicitely ?

Comment: No need to use NSNumber there just pass `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

u can use it for root directory only

> Starting in iOS 5.1, apps can use either
>   `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` or `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` file
>   system properties to **exclude files and directories** from backups.

In details look [Technical Q&A QA1719](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html)